# Question about tangent planes for 2D surfaces?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, euclidean-geometry

Suppose we have two 2D surfaces $S_1, S_2$, both are bounded by $(0,1)^3$, close, smooth. And they are both tangent to a straight line $l$, so will $S_1, S_2$ have common tangent plane?

Comment: Suppose two planes have a line in common; must they be the same plane?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang : the surfaces here should be bounded and closed

Comment: Yes, as noted in the question. The first comment is germane nonetheless.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang: But plane is neither close nor bounded.